# Find and replace in JSON javascript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am working on creating graphs using d3.js and I am using a JSON file as the input. I need to parse the date and time format for the x axis. And this is the code i tried.

```
d3.json('data/fake_users11.json', function(data) {

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
var old = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/\//g, "-");
data = JSON.parse(old); //convert back to array
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});
```

the json file is something like this

```
[
    {
        "date": "02\/18\/2016 18:02:38",
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "date": "02\/18\/2016 18:02:45",
        "value": 20
    },
    {
        "date": "02\/18\/2016 18:02:50",
        "value": 30
    }
]
```

The required format is 02-18-2016 18:02:50. But i am just getting an error. I know im close. Can someone point out the mistake here ?
Thanks.

Comment: *"i am just getting an error"* That sure sounds like a piece of information that would make sense to include in your question.

Comment: The error seems to be from d3.js because the data isnt as required for the d3 time format to parse.

Comment: Add a `console.log` to the `foreach` function to display the values being sent to `parseData` and the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong format, I think.

The year is at the end in your dates, but you are trying to parse it at the beginning:

```
var parseDateWrong = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
```

It should be instead:

```
var parseDateOk = d3.time.format("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S").parse;
```

Please refer to [jfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/etpcz31t/1/) to see what happens

I think that you can now use directly the json you receive without substituting the / with the -:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});
```

Comment: beautiful! yea solved it.! i didnt even think this could have been an issue!

Comment: I haven't changed your code, but I think that it is not necessary to substitute the / with the -

Comment: yea but i want it to be a - thats why im replacing it :p...thanks anyways bro :)